# Closing Swing JTabbedPane tabs in Java 1.5?

Tags: java, user-interface, swing

Java 6 introduces "Tab Components" and allows you to add arbitrary components to the tab.  But, if you're stuck in Java 1.5, and need to provide the same use case, what are the alternatives?  (I just need users to be able to close tabs...there has to have been a workaround for this prior to the release of Java 6.)

Comment: Changed the title to better reflect the actual question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Caveat: I have not tried any of these:

- a [discussion](http://forums.sun.com/thread.jspa?threadID=337070) on the subject with code.
- Here is a [JavaWorld Article](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-09-2004/jw-0906-tabbedpane.html)
- Here is a [CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/tabs/JTabbedPane.aspx)